# List of countries and country dialing codes for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm looking a list of countries and their dialing codes available in perhaps a plist file or Objective-C dictionary.

I know there are some lists in PHP like this:
https://gist.github.com/260468
and if it comes to it I'll port it manually, but that's error prone.

Comment: You can also check this framework https://github.com/NikKovIos/NKVPhonePicker to automate country code picking.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[Quite simple](http://pastebin.com/adNADRzU). Open the PHP version in vim, enter one command, and clean up the tags and separator.

```
:%s/.*= \='\(.*\) (\(+\=.*\))';.*/@"\1" : @"\2",
```

This is why everyone should learn vim.

(New object literal syntax - requires XCode 4.5/clang 4.1).

---

The transformed list, to prevent link rot:

```
// Country code
NSDictionary *codes = @{
@"Canada"                                       : @"+1",
@"China"                                        : @"+86",
@"France"                                       : @"+33",
@"Germany"                                      : @"+49",
@"India"                                        : @"+91",
@"Japan"                                        : @"+81",
@"Pakistan"                                     : @"+92",
@"United Kingdom"                               : @"+44",
@"United States"                                : @"+1",
@"Abkhazia"                                     : @"+7 840",
@"Abkhazia"                                     : @"+7 940",
@"Afghanistan"                                  : @"+93",
@"Albania"                                      : @"+355",
@"Algeria"                                      : @"+213",
@"American Samoa"                               : @"+1 684",
@"Andorra"                                      : @"+376",
@"Angola"                                       : @"+244",
@"Anguilla"                                     : @"+1 264",
@"Antigua and Barbuda"                          : @"+1 268",
@"Argentina"                                    : @"+54",
@"Armenia"                                      : @"+374",
@"Aruba"                                        : @"+297",
@"Ascension"                                    : @"+247",
@"Australia"                                    : @"+61",
@"Australian External Territories"              : @"+672",
@"Austria"                                      : @"+43",
@"Azerbaijan"                                   : @"+994",
@"Bahamas"                                      : @"+1 242",
@"Bahrain"                                      : @"+973",
@"Bangladesh"                                   : @"+880",
@"Barbados"                                     : @"+1 246",
@"Barbuda"                                      : @"+1 268",
@"Belarus"                                      : @"+375",
@"Belgium"                                      : @"+32",
@"Belize"                                       : @"+501",
@"Benin"                                        : @"+229",
@"Bermuda"                                      : @"+1 441",
@"Bhutan"                                       : @"+975",
@"Bolivia"                                      : @"+591",
@"Bosnia and Herzegovina"                       : @"+387",
@"Botswana"                                     : @"+267",
@"Brazil"                                       : @"+55",
@"British Indian Ocean Territory"               : @"+246",
@"British Virgin Islands"                       : @"+1 284",
@"Brunei"                                       : @"+673",
@"Bulgaria"                                     : @"+359",
@"Burkina Faso"                                 : @"+226",
@"Burundi"                                      : @"+257",
@"Cambodia"                                     : @"+855",
@"Cameroon"                                     : @"+237",
@"Canada"                                       : @"+1",
@"Cape Verde"                                   : @"+238",
@"Cayman Islands"                               : @"+ 345",
@"Central African Republic"                     : @"+236",
@"Chad"                                         : @"+235",
@"Chile"                                        : @"+56",
@"China"                                        : @"+86",
@"Christmas Island"                             : @"+61",
@"Cocos-Keeling Islands"                        : @"+61",
@"Colombia"                                     : @"+57",
@"Comoros"                                      : @"+269",
@"Congo"                                        : @"+242",
@"Congo, Dem. Rep. of (Zaire)"                  : @"+243",
@"Cook Islands"                                 : @"+682",
@"Costa Rica"                                   : @"+506",
@"Ivory Coast"                                  : @"+225",
@"Croatia"                                      : @"+385",
@"Cuba"                                         : @"+53",
@"Curacao"                                      : @"+599",
@"Cyprus"                                       : @"+537",
@"Czech Republic"                               : @"+420",
@"Denmark"                                      : @"+45",
@"Diego Garcia"                                 : @"+246",
@"Djibouti"                                     : @"+253",
@"Dominica"                                     : @"+1 767",
@"Dominican Republic"                           : @"+1 809",
@"Dominican Republic"                           : @"+1 829",
@"Dominican Republic"                           : @"+1 849",
@"East Timor"                                   : @"+670",
@"Easter Island"                                : @"+56",
@"Ecuador"                                      : @"+593",
@"Egypt"                                        : @"+20",
@"El Salvador"                                  : @"+503",
@"Equatorial Guinea"                            : @"+240",
@"Eritrea"                                      : @"+291",
@"Estonia"                                      : @"+372",
@"Ethiopia"                                     : @"+251",
@"Falkland Islands"                             : @"+500",
@"Faroe Islands"                                : @"+298",
@"Fiji"                                         : @"+679",
@"Finland"                                      : @"+358",
@"France"                                       : @"+33",
@"French Antilles"                              : @"+596",
@"French Guiana"                                : @"+594",
@"French Polynesia"                             : @"+689",
@"Gabon"                                        : @"+241",
@"Gambia"                                       : @"+220",
@"Georgia"                                      : @"+995",
@"Germany"                                      : @"+49",
@"Ghana"                                        : @"+233",
@"Gibraltar"                                    : @"+350",
@"Greece"                                       : @"+30",
@"Greenland"                                    : @"+299",
@"Grenada"                                      : @"+1 473",
@"Guadeloupe"                                   : @"+590",
@"Guam"                                         : @"+1 671",
@"Guatemala"                                    : @"+502",
@"Guinea"                                       : @"+224",
@"Guinea-Bissau"                                : @"+245",
@"Guyana"                                       : @"+595",
@"Haiti"                                        : @"+509",
@"Honduras"                                     : @"+504",
@"Hong Kong SAR China"                          : @"+852",
@"Hungary"                                      : @"+36",
@"Iceland"                                      : @"+354",
@"India"                                        : @"+91",
@"Indonesia"                                    : @"+62",
@"Iran"                                         : @"+98",
@"Iraq"                                         : @"+964",
@"Ireland"                                      : @"+353",
@"Israel"                                       : @"+972",
@"Italy"                                        : @"+39",
@"Jamaica"                                      : @"+1 876",
@"Japan"                                        : @"+81",
@"Jordan"                                       : @"+962",
@"Kazakhstan"                                   : @"+7 7",
@"Kenya"                                        : @"+254",
@"Kiribati"                                     : @"+686",
@"North Korea"                                  : @"+850",
@"South Korea"                                  : @"+82",
@"Kuwait"                                       : @"+965",
@"Kyrgyzstan"                                   : @"+996",
@"Laos"                                         : @"+856",
@"Latvia"                                       : @"+371",
@"Lebanon"                                      : @"+961",
@"Lesotho"                                      : @"+266",
@"Liberia"                                      : @"+231",
@"Libya"                                        : @"+218",
@"Liechtenstein"                                : @"+423",
@"Lithuania"                                    : @"+370",
@"Luxembourg"                                   : @"+352",
@"Macau SAR China"                              : @"+853",
@"Macedonia"                                    : @"+389",
@"Madagascar"                                   : @"+261",
@"Malawi"                                       : @"+265",
@"Malaysia"                                     : @"+60",
@"Maldives"                                     : @"+960",
@"Mali"                                         : @"+223",
@"Malta"                                        : @"+356",
@"Marshall Islands"                             : @"+692",
@"Martinique"                                   : @"+596",
@"Mauritania"                                   : @"+222",
@"Mauritius"                                    : @"+230",
@"Mayotte"                                      : @"+262",
@"Mexico"                                       : @"+52",
@"Micronesia"                                   : @"+691",
@"Midway Island"                                : @"+1 808",
@"Micronesia"                                   : @"+691",
@"Moldova"                                      : @"+373",
@"Monaco"                                       : @"+377",
@"Mongolia"                                     : @"+976",
@"Montenegro"                                   : @"+382",
@"Montserrat"                                   : @"+1664",
@"Morocco"                                      : @"+212",
@"Myanmar"                                      : @"+95",
@"Namibia"                                      : @"+264",
@"Nauru"                                        : @"+674",
@"Nepal"                                        : @"+977",
@"Netherlands"                                  : @"+31",
@"Netherlands Antilles"                         : @"+599",
@"Nevis"                                        : @"+1 869",
@"New Caledonia"                                : @"+687",
@"New Zealand"                                  : @"+64",
@"Nicaragua"                                    : @"+505",
@"Niger"                                        : @"+227",
@"Nigeria"                                      : @"+234",
@"Niue"                                         : @"+683",
@"Norfolk Island"                               : @"+672",
@"Northern Mariana Islands"                     : @"+1 670",
@"Norway"                                       : @"+47",
@"Oman"                                         : @"+968",
@"Pakistan"                                     : @"+92",
@"Palau"                                        : @"+680",
@"Palestinian Territory"                        : @"+970",
@"Panama"                                       : @"+507",
@"Papua New Guinea"                             : @"+675",
@"Paraguay"                                     : @"+595",
@"Peru"                                         : @"+51",
@"Philippines"                                  : @"+63",
@"Poland"                                       : @"+48",
@"Portugal"                                     : @"+351",
@"Puerto Rico"                                  : @"+1 787",
@"Puerto Rico"                                  : @"+1 939",
@"Qatar"                                        : @"+974",
@"Reunion"                                      : @"+262",
@"Romania"                                      : @"+40",
@"Russia"                                       : @"+7",
@"Rwanda"                                       : @"+250",
@"Samoa"                                        : @"+685",
@"San Marino"                                   : @"+378",
@"Saudi Arabia"                                 : @"+966",
@"Senegal"                                      : @"+221",
@"Serbia"                                       : @"+381",
@"Seychelles"                                   : @"+248",
@"Sierra Leone"                                 : @"+232",
@"Singapore"                                    : @"+65",
@"Slovakia"                                     : @"+421",
@"Slovenia"                                     : @"+386",
@"Solomon Islands"                              : @"+677",
@"South Africa"                                 : @"+27",
@"South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands" : @"+500",
@"Spain"                                        : @"+34",
@"Sri Lanka"                                    : @"+94",
@"Sudan"                                        : @"+249",
@"Suriname"                                     : @"+597",
@"Swaziland"                                    : @"+268",
@"Sweden"                                       : @"+46",
@"Switzerland"                                  : @"+41",
@"Syria"                                        : @"+963",
@"Taiwan"                                       : @"+886",
@"Tajikistan"                                   : @"+992",
@"Tanzania"                                     : @"+255",
@"Thailand"                                     : @"+66",
@"Timor Leste"                                  : @"+670",
@"Togo"                                         : @"+228",
@"Tokelau"                                      : @"+690",
@"Tonga"                                        : @"+676",
@"Trinidad and Tobago"                          : @"+1 868",
@"Tunisia"                                      : @"+216",
@"Turkey"                                       : @"+90",
@"Turkmenistan"                                 : @"+993",
@"Turks and Caicos Islands"                     : @"+1 649",
@"Tuvalu"                                       : @"+688",
@"Uganda"                                       : @"+256",
@"Ukraine"                                      : @"+380",
@"United Arab Emirates"                         : @"+971",
@"United Kingdom"                               : @"+44",
@"United States"                                : @"+1",
@"Uruguay"                                      : @"+598",
@"U.S. Virgin Islands"                          : @"+1 340",
@"Uzbekistan"                                   : @"+998",
@"Vanuatu"                                      : @"+678",
@"Venezuela"                                    : @"+58",
@"Vietnam"                                      : @"+84",
@"Wake Island"                                  : @"+1 808",
@"Wallis and Futuna"                            : @"+681",
@"Yemen"                                        : @"+967",
@"Zambia"                                       : @"+260",
@"Zanzibar"                                     : @"+255",
@"Zimbabwe"                                     : @"+263"
};
```

Comment: Woah. Impressive..is that regex?

Comment: Yes, it's a vim-style regex. Basically a BRE, but `\=` instead of `?` for 'zero or one'.

Comment: this has duplicate keys.

Comment: @spaceMonkey, Those countries has multiple country codes

Answer (score 23):

```
NSDictionary *dictCodes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
@"93",@"AF",@"355",@"AL",@"213",@"DZ",@"1",@"AS",
@"376",@"AD",@"244",@"AO",@"1",@"AI",@"1",@"AG",
@"54",@"AR",@"374",@"AM",@"297",@"AW",@"61",@"AU",
@"43",@"AT",@"994",@"AZ",@"1",@"BS",@"973",@"BH",
@"880",@"BD",@"1",@"BB",@"375",@"BY",@"32",@"BE",
@"501",@"BZ",@"229",@"BJ",@"1",@"BM",@"975",@"BT",
@"387",@"BA",@"267",@"BW",@"55",@"BR",@"246",@"IO",
@"359",@"BG",@"226",@"BF",@"257",@"BI",@"855",@"KH",
@"237",@"CM",@"1",@"CA",@"238",@"CV",@"345",@"KY",
@"236",@"CF",@"235",@"TD",@"56",@"CL",@"86",@"CN",
@"61",@"CX",@"57",@"CO",@"269",@"KM",@"242",@"CG",
@"682",@"CK",@"506",@"CR",@"385",@"HR",@"53",@"CU",
@"537",@"CY",@"420",@"CZ",@"45",@"DK",@"253",@"DJ",
@"1",@"DM",@"1",@"DO",@"593",@"EC",@"20",@"EG",
@"503",@"SV",@"240",@"GQ",@"291",@"ER",@"372",@"EE",
@"251",@"ET",@"298",@"FO",@"679",@"FJ",@"358",@"FI",
@"33",@"FR",@"594",@"GF",@"689",@"PF",@"241",@"GA",
@"220",@"GM",@"995",@"GE",@"49",@"DE",@"233",@"GH",
@"350",@"GI",@"30",@"GR",@"299",@"GL",@"1",@"GD",
@"590",@"GP",@"1",@"GU",@"502",@"GT",@"224",@"GN",
@"245",@"GW",@"595",@"GY",@"509",@"HT",@"504",@"HN",
@"36",@"HU",@"354",@"IS",@"91",@"IN",@"62",@"ID",
@"964",@"IQ",@"353",@"IE",@"972",@"IL",@"39",@"IT",
@"1",@"JM",@"81",@"JP",@"962",@"JO",@"77",@"KZ",
@"254",@"KE",@"686",@"KI",@"965",@"KW",@"996",@"KG",
@"371",@"LV",@"961",@"LB",@"266",@"LS",@"231",@"LR",
@"423",@"LI",@"370",@"LT",@"352",@"LU",@"261",@"MG",
@"265",@"MW",@"60",@"MY",@"960",@"MV",@"223",@"ML",
@"356",@"MT",@"692",@"MH",@"596",@"MQ",@"222",@"MR",
@"230",@"MU",@"262",@"YT",@"52",@"MX",@"377",@"MC",
@"976",@"MN",@"382",@"ME",@"1",@"MS",@"212",@"MA",
@"95",@"MM",@"264",@"NA",@"674",@"NR",@"977",@"NP",
@"31",@"NL",@"599",@"AN",@"687",@"NC",@"64",@"NZ",
@"505",@"NI",@"227",@"NE",@"234",@"NG",@"683",@"NU",
@"672",@"NF",@"1",@"MP",@"47",@"NO",@"968",@"OM",
@"92",@"PK",@"680",@"PW",@"507",@"PA",@"675",@"PG",
@"595",@"PY",@"51",@"PE",@"63",@"PH",@"48",@"PL",
@"351",@"PT",@"1",@"PR",@"974",@"QA",@"40",@"RO",
@"250",@"RW",@"685",@"WS",@"378",@"SM",@"966",@"SA",
@"221",@"SN",@"381",@"RS",@"248",@"SC",@"232",@"SL",
@"65",@"SG",@"421",@"SK",@"386",@"SI",@"677",@"SB",
@"27",@"ZA",@"500",@"GS",@"34",@"ES",@"94",@"LK",
@"249",@"SD",@"597",@"SR",@"268",@"SZ",@"46",@"SE",
@"41",@"CH",@"992",@"TJ",@"66",@"TH",@"228",@"TG",
@"690",@"TK",@"676",@"TO",@"1",@"TT",@"216",@"TN",
@"90",@"TR",@"993",@"TM",@"1",@"TC",@"688",@"TV",
@"256",@"UG",@"380",@"UA",@"971",@"AE",@"44",@"GB",
@"1",@"US",@"598",@"UY",@"998",@"UZ",@"678",@"VU",
@"681",@"WF",@"967",@"YE",@"260",@"ZM",@"263",@"ZW",
@"591",@"BO",@"673",@"BN",@"61",@"CC",@"243",@"CD",
@"225",@"CI",@"500",@"FK",@"44",@"GG",@"379",@"VA",
@"852",@"HK",@"98",@"IR",@"44",@"IM",@"44",@"JE",
@"850",@"KP",@"82",@"KR",@"856",@"LA",@"218",@"LY",
@"853",@"MO",@"389",@"MK",@"691",@"FM",@"373",@"MD",
@"258",@"MZ",@"970",@"PS",@"872",@"PN",@"262",@"RE",
@"7",@"RU",@"590",@"BL",@"290",@"SH",@"1",@"KN",
@"1",@"LC",@"590",@"MF",@"508",@"PM",@"1",@"VC",
@"239",@"ST",@"252",@"SO",@"47",@"SJ",@"963",@"SY",
@"886",@"TW",@"255",@"TZ",@"670",@"TL",@"58",@"VE",
@"84",@"VN",@"1",@"VG",@"1",@"VI",@"672",@"AQ",
@"358",@"AX",@"47",@"BV",@"599",@"BQ",@"599",@"CW",
@"689",@"TF",@"1",@"SX",@"211",@"SS"​,@"212",@"EH",
@"972",@"IL", nil];
```

Comment: If your doing anything with phone numbers and your dealing with users in every country, check out https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/ its the greatest piece of open source code for developers

Comment: where is AQ aka Antartica

Comment: Add to this list @"672",@"AQ",@"358",               @"AX",@"47",@"BV",@"599",@"BQ",@"599",@"CW",@"689",@"TF",@"1",@"SX",@"211",@"SS",@"212",@"EH",

Comment: I miss "BQ - 599", what country is it please?

Comment: Add also: @"247",@"AC",@"246",@"DG",@"34",@"EA",@"672",@"HM", @"922",@"IC",@"290",@"TA",@"1",@"UM",@"383",@"XK",

Answer (score 8):

With thanks to AlBeebe, I used that to swap it around to convert the country code to a dialling prefix in a Swift Dictionary declaration.

```
let prefixCodes = ["AF": "93", "AE": "971", "AL": "355", "AN": "599", "AS":"1", "AD": "376", "AO": "244", "AI": "1", "AG":"1", "AR": "54","AM": "374", "AW": "297", "AU":"61", "AT": "43","AZ": "994", "BS": "1", "BH":"973", "BF": "226","BI": "257", "BD": "880", "BB": "1", "BY": "375", "BE":"32","BZ": "501", "BJ": "229", "BM": "1", "BT":"975", "BA": "387", "BW": "267", "BR": "55", "BG": "359", "BO": "591", "BL": "590", "BN": "673", "CC": "61", "CD":"243","CI": "225", "KH":"855", "CM": "237", "CA": "1", "CV": "238", "KY":"345", "CF":"236", "CH": "41", "CL": "56", "CN":"86","CX": "61", "CO": "57", "KM": "269", "CG":"242", "CK": "682", "CR": "506", "CU":"53", "CY":"537","CZ": "420", "DE": "49", "DK": "45", "DJ":"253", "DM": "1", "DO": "1", "DZ": "213", "EC": "593", "EG":"20", "ER": "291", "EE":"372","ES": "34", "ET": "251", "FM": "691", "FK": "500", "FO": "298", "FJ": "679", "FI":"358", "FR": "33", "GB":"44", "GF": "594", "GA":"241", "GS": "500", "GM":"220", "GE":"995","GH":"233", "GI": "350", "GQ": "240", "GR": "30", "GG": "44", "GL": "299", "GD":"1", "GP": "590", "GU": "1", "GT": "502", "GN":"224","GW": "245", "GY": "595", "HT": "509", "HR": "385", "HN":"504", "HU": "36", "HK": "852", "IR": "98", "IM": "44", "IL": "972", "IO":"246", "IS": "354", "IN": "91", "ID":"62", "IQ":"964", "IE": "353","IT":"39", "JM":"1", "JP": "81", "JO": "962", "JE":"44", "KP": "850", "KR": "82","KZ":"77", "KE": "254", "KI": "686", "KW": "965", "KG":"996","KN":"1", "LC": "1", "LV": "371", "LB": "961", "LK":"94", "LS": "266", "LR":"231", "LI": "423", "LT": "370", "LU": "352", "LA": "856", "LY":"218", "MO": "853", "MK": "389", "MG":"261", "MW": "265", "MY": "60","MV": "960", "ML":"223", "MT": "356", "MH": "692", "MQ": "596", "MR":"222", "MU": "230", "MX": "52","MC": "377", "MN": "976", "ME": "382", "MP": "1", "MS": "1", "MA":"212", "MM": "95", "MF": "590", "MD":"373", "MZ": "258", "NA":"264", "NR":"674", "NP":"977", "NL": "31","NC": "687", "NZ":"64", "NI": "505", "NE": "227", "NG": "234", "NU":"683", "NF": "672", "NO": "47","OM": "968", "PK": "92", "PM": "508", "PW": "680", "PF": "689", "PA": "507", "PG":"675", "PY": "595", "PE": "51", "PH": "63", "PL":"48", "PN": "872","PT": "351", "PR": "1","PS": "970", "QA": "974", "RO":"40", "RE":"262", "RS": "381", "RU": "7", "RW": "250", "SM": "378", "SA":"966", "SN": "221", "SC": "248", "SL":"232","SG": "65", "SK": "421", "SI": "386", "SB":"677", "SH": "290", "SD": "249", "SR": "597","SZ": "268", "SE":"46", "SV": "503", "ST": "239","SO": "252", "SJ": "47", "SY":"963", "TW": "886", "TZ": "255", "TL": "670", "TD": "235", "TJ": "992", "TH": "66", "TG":"228", "TK": "690", "TO": "676", "TT": "1", "TN":"216","TR": "90", "TM": "993", "TC": "1", "TV":"688", "UG": "256", "UA": "380", "US": "1", "UY": "598","UZ": "998", "VA":"379", "VE":"58", "VN": "84", "VG": "1", "VI": "1","VC":"1", "VU":"678", "WS": "685", "WF": "681", "YE": "967", "YT": "262","ZA": "27" , "ZM": "260", "ZW":"263"]
```

Answer (score 8):

I generated json file for this list:

```
{
  "countries": [
    {
      "code": "+7 840",
      "name": "Abkhazia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+93",
      "name": "Afghanistan"
    },
    {
      "code": "+355",
      "name": "Albania"
    },
    {
      "code": "+213",
      "name": "Algeria"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 684",
      "name": "American Samoa"
    },
    {
      "code": "+376",
      "name": "Andorra"
    },
    {
      "code": "+244",
      "name": "Angola"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 264",
      "name": "Anguilla"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 268",
      "name": "Antigua and Barbuda"
    },
    {
      "code": "+54",
      "name": "Argentina"
    },
    {
      "code": "+374",
      "name": "Armenia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+297",
      "name": "Aruba"
    },
    {
      "code": "+247",
      "name": "Ascension"
    },
    {
      "code": "+61",
      "name": "Australia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+672",
      "name": "Australian External Territories"
    },
    {
      "code": "+43",
      "name": "Austria"
    },
    {
      "code": "+994",
      "name": "Azerbaijan"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 242",
      "name": "Bahamas"
    },
    {
      "code": "+973",
      "name": "Bahrain"
    },
    {
      "code": "+880",
      "name": "Bangladesh"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 246",
      "name": "Barbados"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 268",
      "name": "Barbuda"
    },
    {
      "code": "+375",
      "name": "Belarus"
    },
    {
      "code": "+32",
      "name": "Belgium"
    },
    {
      "code": "+501",
      "name": "Belize"
    },
    {
      "code": "+229",
      "name": "Benin"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 441",
      "name": "Bermuda"
    },
    {
      "code": "+975",
      "name": "Bhutan"
    },
    {
      "code": "+591",
      "name": "Bolivia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+387",
      "name": "Bosnia and Herzegovina"
    },
    {
      "code": "+267",
      "name": "Botswana"
    },
    {
      "code": "+55",
      "name": "Brazil"
    },
    {
      "code": "+246",
      "name": "British Indian Ocean Territory"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 284",
      "name": "British Virgin Islands"
    },
    {
      "code": "+673",
      "name": "Brunei"
    },
    {
      "code": "+359",
      "name": "Bulgaria"
    },
    {
      "code": "+226",
      "name": "Burkina Faso"
    },
    {
      "code": "+257",
      "name": "Burundi"
    },
    {
      "code": "+855",
      "name": "Cambodia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+237",
      "name": "Cameroon"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1",
      "name": "Canada"
    },
    {
      "code": "+238",
      "name": "Cape Verde"
    },
    {
      "code": "+ 345",
      "name": "Cayman Islands"
    },
    {
      "code": "+236",
      "name": "Central African Republic"
    },
    {
      "code": "+235",
      "name": "Chad"
    },
    {
      "code": "+56",
      "name": "Chile"
    },
    {
      "code": "+86",
      "name": "China"
    },
    {
      "code": "+61",
      "name": "Christmas Island"
    },
    {
      "code": "+61",
      "name": "Cocos-Keeling Islands"
    },
    {
      "code": "+57",
      "name": "Colombia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+269",
      "name": "Comoros"
    },
    {
      "code": "+242",
      "name": "Congo"
    },
    {
      "code": "+243",
      "name": "Congo, Dem. Rep. of (Zaire)"
    },
    {
      "code": "+682",
      "name": "Cook Islands"
    },
    {
      "code": "+506",
      "name": "Costa Rica"
    },
    {
      "code": "+385",
      "name": "Croatia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+53",
      "name": "Cuba"
    },
    {
      "code": "+599",
      "name": "Curacao"
    },
    {
      "code": "+537",
      "name": "Cyprus"
    },
    {
      "code": "+420",
      "name": "Czech Republic"
    },
    {
      "code": "+45",
      "name": "Denmark"
    },
    {
      "code": "+246",
      "name": "Diego Garcia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+253",
      "name": "Djibouti"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 767",
      "name": "Dominica"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 809",
      "name": "Dominican Republic"
    },
    {
      "code": "+670",
      "name": "East Timor"
    },
    {
      "code": "+56",
      "name": "Easter Island"
    },
    {
      "code": "+593",
      "name": "Ecuador"
    },
    {
      "code": "+20",
      "name": "Egypt"
    },
    {
      "code": "+503",
      "name": "El Salvador"
    },
    {
      "code": "+240",
      "name": "Equatorial Guinea"
    },
    {
      "code": "+291",
      "name": "Eritrea"
    },
    {
      "code": "+372",
      "name": "Estonia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+251",
      "name": "Ethiopia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+500",
      "name": "Falkland Islands"
    },
    {
      "code": "+298",
      "name": "Faroe Islands"
    },
    {
      "code": "+679",
      "name": "Fiji"
    },
    {
      "code": "+358",
      "name": "Finland"
    },
    {
      "code": "+33",
      "name": "France"
    },
    {
      "code": "+596",
      "name": "French Antilles"
    },
    {
      "code": "+594",
      "name": "French Guiana"
    },
    {
      "code": "+689",
      "name": "French Polynesia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+241",
      "name": "Gabon"
    },
    {
      "code": "+220",
      "name": "Gambia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+995",
      "name": "Georgia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+49",
      "name": "Germany"
    },
    {
      "code": "+233",
      "name": "Ghana"
    },
    {
      "code": "+350",
      "name": "Gibraltar"
    },
    {
      "code": "+30",
      "name": "Greece"
    },
    {
      "code": "+299",
      "name": "Greenland"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 473",
      "name": "Grenada"
    },
    {
      "code": "+590",
      "name": "Guadeloupe"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 671",
      "name": "Guam"
    },
    {
      "code": "+502",
      "name": "Guatemala"
    },
    {
      "code": "+224",
      "name": "Guinea"
    },
    {
      "code": "+245",
      "name": "Guinea-Bissau"
    },
    {
      "code": "+595",
      "name": "Guyana"
    },
    {
      "code": "+509",
      "name": "Haiti"
    },
    {
      "code": "+504",
      "name": "Honduras"
    },
    {
      "code": "+852",
      "name": "Hong Kong SAR China"
    },
    {
      "code": "+36",
      "name": "Hungary"
    },
    {
      "code": "+354",
      "name": "Iceland"
    },
    {
      "code": "+91",
      "name": "India"
    },
    {
      "code": "+62",
      "name": "Indonesia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+98",
      "name": "Iran"
    },
    {
      "code": "+964",
      "name": "Iraq"
    },
    {
      "code": "+353",
      "name": "Ireland"
    },
    {
      "code": "+972",
      "name": "Israel"
    },
    {
      "code": "+39",
      "name": "Italy"
    },
    {
      "code": "+225",
      "name": "Ivory Coast"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 876",
      "name": "Jamaica"
    },
    {
      "code": "+81",
      "name": "Japan"
    },
    {
      "code": "+962",
      "name": "Jordan"
    },
    {
      "code": "+7 7",
      "name": "Kazakhstan"
    },
    {
      "code": "+254",
      "name": "Kenya"
    },
    {
      "code": "+686",
      "name": "Kiribati"
    },
    {
      "code": "+965",
      "name": "Kuwait"
    },
    {
      "code": "+996",
      "name": "Kyrgyzstan"
    },
    {
      "code": "+856",
      "name": "Laos"
    },
    {
      "code": "+371",
      "name": "Latvia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+961",
      "name": "Lebanon"
    },
    {
      "code": "+266",
      "name": "Lesotho"
    },
    {
      "code": "+231",
      "name": "Liberia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+218",
      "name": "Libya"
    },
    {
      "code": "+423",
      "name": "Liechtenstein"
    },
    {
      "code": "+370",
      "name": "Lithuania"
    },
    {
      "code": "+352",
      "name": "Luxembourg"
    },
    {
      "code": "+853",
      "name": "Macau SAR China"
    },
    {
      "code": "+389",
      "name": "Macedonia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+261",
      "name": "Madagascar"
    },
    {
      "code": "+265",
      "name": "Malawi"
    },
    {
      "code": "+60",
      "name": "Malaysia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+960",
      "name": "Maldives"
    },
    {
      "code": "+223",
      "name": "Mali"
    },
    {
      "code": "+356",
      "name": "Malta"
    },
    {
      "code": "+692",
      "name": "Marshall Islands"
    },
    {
      "code": "+596",
      "name": "Martinique"
    },
    {
      "code": "+222",
      "name": "Mauritania"
    },
    {
      "code": "+230",
      "name": "Mauritius"
    },
    {
      "code": "+262",
      "name": "Mayotte"
    },
    {
      "code": "+52",
      "name": "Mexico"
    },
    {
      "code": "+691",
      "name": "Micronesia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 808",
      "name": "Midway Island"
    },
    {
      "code": "+373",
      "name": "Moldova"
    },
    {
      "code": "+377",
      "name": "Monaco"
    },
    {
      "code": "+976",
      "name": "Mongolia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+382",
      "name": "Montenegro"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1664",
      "name": "Montserrat"
    },
    {
      "code": "+212",
      "name": "Morocco"
    },
    {
      "code": "+95",
      "name": "Myanmar"
    },
    {
      "code": "+264",
      "name": "Namibia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+674",
      "name": "Nauru"
    },
    {
      "code": "+977",
      "name": "Nepal"
    },
    {
      "code": "+31",
      "name": "Netherlands"
    },
    {
      "code": "+599",
      "name": "Netherlands Antilles"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 869",
      "name": "Nevis"
    },
    {
      "code": "+687",
      "name": "New Caledonia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+64",
      "name": "New Zealand"
    },
    {
      "code": "+505",
      "name": "Nicaragua"
    },
    {
      "code": "+227",
      "name": "Niger"
    },
    {
      "code": "+234",
      "name": "Nigeria"
    },
    {
      "code": "+683",
      "name": "Niue"
    },
    {
      "code": "+672",
      "name": "Norfolk Island"
    },
    {
      "code": "+850",
      "name": "North Korea"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 670",
      "name": "Northern Mariana Islands"
    },
    {
      "code": "+47",
      "name": "Norway"
    },
    {
      "code": "+968",
      "name": "Oman"
    },
    {
      "code": "+92",
      "name": "Pakistan"
    },
    {
      "code": "+680",
      "name": "Palau"
    },
    {
      "code": "+970",
      "name": "Palestinian Territory"
    },
    {
      "code": "+507",
      "name": "Panama"
    },
    {
      "code": "+675",
      "name": "Papua New Guinea"
    },
    {
      "code": "+595",
      "name": "Paraguay"
    },
    {
      "code": "+51",
      "name": "Peru"
    },
    {
      "code": "+63",
      "name": "Philippines"
    },
    {
      "code": "+48",
      "name": "Poland"
    },
    {
      "code": "+351",
      "name": "Portugal"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 787",
      "name": "Puerto Rico"
    },
    {
      "code": "+974",
      "name": "Qatar"
    },
    {
      "code": "+262",
      "name": "Reunion"
    },
    {
      "code": "+40",
      "name": "Romania"
    },
    {
      "code": "+7",
      "name": "Russia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+250",
      "name": "Rwanda"
    },
    {
      "code": "+685",
      "name": "Samoa"
    },
    {
      "code": "+378",
      "name": "San Marino"
    },
    {
      "code": "+966",
      "name": "Saudi Arabia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+221",
      "name": "Senegal"
    },
    {
      "code": "+381",
      "name": "Serbia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+248",
      "name": "Seychelles"
    },
    {
      "code": "+232",
      "name": "Sierra Leone"
    },
    {
      "code": "+65",
      "name": "Singapore"
    },
    {
      "code": "+421",
      "name": "Slovakia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+386",
      "name": "Slovenia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+677",
      "name": "Solomon Islands"
    },
    {
      "code": "+27",
      "name": "South Africa"
    },
    {
      "code": "+500",
      "name": "South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands"
    },
    {
      "code": "+82",
      "name": "South Korea"
    },
    {
      "code": "+34",
      "name": "Spain"
    },
    {
      "code": "+94",
      "name": "Sri Lanka"
    },
    {
      "code": "+249",
      "name": "Sudan"
    },
    {
      "code": "+597",
      "name": "Suriname"
    },
    {
      "code": "+268",
      "name": "Swaziland"
    },
    {
      "code": "+46",
      "name": "Sweden"
    },
    {
      "code": "+41",
      "name": "Switzerland"
    },
    {
      "code": "+963",
      "name": "Syria"
    },
    {
      "code": "+886",
      "name": "Taiwan"
    },
    {
      "code": "+992",
      "name": "Tajikistan"
    },
    {
      "code": "+255",
      "name": "Tanzania"
    },
    {
      "code": "+66",
      "name": "Thailand"
    },
    {
      "code": "+670",
      "name": "Timor Leste"
    },
    {
      "code": "+228",
      "name": "Togo"
    },
    {
      "code": "+690",
      "name": "Tokelau"
    },
    {
      "code": "+676",
      "name": "Tonga"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 868",
      "name": "Trinidad and Tobago"
    },
    {
      "code": "+216",
      "name": "Tunisia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+90",
      "name": "Turkey"
    },
    {
      "code": "+993",
      "name": "Turkmenistan"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 649",
      "name": "Turks and Caicos Islands"
    },
    {
      "code": "+688",
      "name": "Tuvalu"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 340",
      "name": "U.S. Virgin Islands"
    },
    {
      "code": "+256",
      "name": "Uganda"
    },
    {
      "code": "+380",
      "name": "Ukraine"
    },
    {
      "code": "+971",
      "name": "United Arab Emirates"
    },
    {
      "code": "+44",
      "name": "United Kingdom"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1",
      "name": "United States"
    },
    {
      "code": "+598",
      "name": "Uruguay"
    },
    {
      "code": "+998",
      "name": "Uzbekistan"
    },
    {
      "code": "+678",
      "name": "Vanuatu"
    },
    {
      "code": "+58",
      "name": "Venezuela"
    },
    {
      "code": "+84",
      "name": "Vietnam"
    },
    {
      "code": "+1 808",
      "name": "Wake Island"
    },
    {
      "code": "+681",
      "name": "Wallis and Futuna"
    },
    {
      "code": "+967",
      "name": "Yemen"
    },
    {
      "code": "+260",
      "name": "Zambia"
    },
    {
      "code": "+255",
      "name": "Zanzibar"
    },
    {
      "code": "+263",
      "name": "Zimbabwe"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Below is the swift version of country dialing code along-with country name:

```
func getCountryCallingCode(countryRegionCode:String) -> [String] {
    let prefix =  ["AF": ["Afghanistan","93"],
                   "AX": ["Aland Islands","358"],
                   "AL": ["Albania","355"],
                   "DZ": ["Algeria","213"],
                   "AS": ["American Samoa","1"],
                   "AD": ["Andorra","376"],
                   "AO": ["Angola","244"],
                   "AI": ["Anguilla","1"],
                   "AQ": ["Antarctica","672"],
                   "AG": ["Antigua and Barbuda","1"],
                   "AR": ["Argentina","54"],
                   "AM": ["Armenia","374"],
                   "AW": ["Aruba","297"],
                   "AU": ["Australia","61"],
                   "AT": ["Austria","43"],
                   "AZ": ["Azerbaijan","994"],
                   "BS": ["Bahamas","1"],
                   "BH": ["Bahrain","973"],
                   "BD": ["Bangladesh","880"],
                   "BB": ["Barbados","1"],
                   "BY": ["Belarus","375"],
                   "BE": ["Belgium","32"],
                   "BZ": ["Belize","501"],
                   "BJ": ["Benin","229"],
                   "BM": ["Bermuda","1"],
                   "BT": ["Bhutan","975"],
                   "BO": ["Bolivia","591"],
                   "BA": ["Bosnia and Herzegovina","387"],
                   "BW": ["Botswana","267"],
                   "BV": ["Bouvet Island","47"],
                   "BQ": ["BQ","599"],
                   "BR": ["Brazil","55"],
                   "IO": ["British Indian Ocean Territory","246"],
                   "VG": ["British Virgin Islands","1"],
                   "BN": ["Brunei Darussalam","673"],
                   "BG": ["Bulgaria","359"],
                   "BF": ["Burkina Faso","226"],
                   "BI": ["Burundi","257"],
                   "KH": ["Cambodia","855"],
                   "CM": ["Cameroon","237"],
                   "CA": ["Canada","1"],
                   "CV": ["Cape Verde","238"],
                   "KY": ["Cayman Islands","345"],
                   "CF": ["Central African Republic","236"],
                   "TD": ["Chad","235"],
                   "CL": ["Chile","56"],
                   "CN": ["China","86"],
                   "CX": ["Christmas Island","61"],
                   "CC": ["Cocos (Keeling) Islands","61"],
                   "CO": ["Colombia","57"],
                   "KM": ["Comoros","269"],
                   "CG": ["Congo (Brazzaville)","242"],
                   "CD": ["Congo, Democratic Republic of the","243"],
                   "CK": ["Cook Islands","682"],
                   "CR": ["Costa Rica","506"],
                   "CI": ["Côte d'Ivoire","225"],
                   "HR": ["Croatia","385"],
                   "CU": ["Cuba","53"],
                   "CW": ["Curacao","599"],
                   "CY": ["Cyprus","537"],
                   "CZ": ["Czech Republic","420"],
                   "DK": ["Denmark","45"],
                   "DJ": ["Djibouti","253"],
                   "DM": ["Dominica","1"],
                   "DO": ["Dominican Republic","1"],
                   "EC": ["Ecuador","593"],
                   "EG": ["Egypt","20"],
                   "SV": ["El Salvador","503"],
                   "GQ": ["Equatorial Guinea","240"],
                   "ER": ["Eritrea","291"],
                   "EE": ["Estonia","372"],
                   "ET": ["Ethiopia","251"],
                   "FK": ["Falkland Islands (Malvinas)","500"],
                   "FO": ["Faroe Islands","298"],
                   "FJ": ["Fiji","679"],
                   "FI": ["Finland","358"],
                   "FR": ["France","33"],
                   "GF": ["French Guiana","594"],
                   "PF": ["French Polynesia","689"],
                   "TF": ["French Southern Territories","689"],
                   "GA": ["Gabon","241"],
                   "GM": ["Gambia","220"],
                   "GE": ["Georgia","995"],
                   "DE": ["Germany","49"],
                   "GH": ["Ghana","233"],
                   "GI": ["Gibraltar","350"],
                   "GR": ["Greece","30"],
                   "GL": ["Greenland","299"],
                   "GD": ["Grenada","1"],
                   "GP": ["Guadeloupe","590"],
                   "GU": ["Guam","1"],
                   "GT": ["Guatemala","502"],
                   "GG": ["Guernsey","44"],
                   "GN": ["Guinea","224"],
                   "GW": ["Guinea-Bissau","245"],
                   "GY": ["Guyana","595"],
                   "HT": ["Haiti","509"],
                   "VA": ["Holy See (Vatican City State)","379"],
                   "HN": ["Honduras","504"],
                   "HK": ["Hong Kong, Special Administrative Region of China","852"],
                   "HU": ["Hungary","36"],
                   "IS": ["Iceland","354"],
                   "IN": ["India","91"],
                   "ID": ["Indonesia","62"],
                   "IR": ["Iran, Islamic Republic of","98"],
                   "IQ": ["Iraq","964"],
                   "IE": ["Ireland","353"],
                   "IM": ["Isle of Man","44"],
                   "IL": ["Israel","972"],
                   "IT": ["Italy","39"],
                   "JM": ["Jamaica","1"],
                   "JP": ["Japan","81"],
                   "JE": ["Jersey","44"],
                   "JO": ["Jordan","962"],
                   "KZ": ["Kazakhstan","77"],
                   "KE": ["Kenya","254"],
                   "KI": ["Kiribati","686"],
                   "KP": ["Korea, Democratic People's Republic of","850"],
                   "KR": ["Korea, Republic of","82"],
                   "KW": ["Kuwait","965"],
                   "KG": ["Kyrgyzstan","996"],
                   "LA": ["Lao PDR","856"],
                   "LV": ["Latvia","371"],
                   "LB": ["Lebanon","961"],
                   "LS": ["Lesotho","266"],
                   "LR": ["Liberia","231"],
                   "LY": ["Libya","218"],
                   "LI": ["Liechtenstein","423"],
                   "LT": ["Lithuania","370"],
                   "LU": ["Luxembourg","352"],
                   "MO": ["Macao, Special Administrative Region of China","853"],
                   "MK": ["Macedonia, Republic of","389"],
                   "MG": ["Madagascar","261"],
                   "MW": ["Malawi","265"],
                   "MY": ["Malaysia","60"],
                   "MV": ["Maldives","960"],
                   "ML": ["Mali","223"],
                   "MT": ["Malta","356"],
                   "MH": ["Marshall Islands","692"],
                   "MQ": ["Martinique","596"],
                   "MR": ["Mauritania","222"],
                   "MU": ["Mauritius","230"],
                   "YT": ["Mayotte","262"],
                   "MX": ["Mexico","52"],
                   "FM": ["Micronesia, Federated States of","691"],
                   "MD": ["Moldova","373"],
                   "MC": ["Monaco","377"],
                   "MN": ["Mongolia","976"],
                   "ME": ["Montenegro","382"],
                   "MS": ["Montserrat","1"],
                   "MA": ["Morocco","212"],
                   "MZ": ["Mozambique","258"],
                   "MM": ["Myanmar","95"],
                   "NA": ["Namibia","264"],
                   "NR": ["Nauru","674"],
                   "NP": ["Nepal","977"],
                   "NL": ["Netherlands","31"],
                   "AN": ["Netherlands Antilles","599"],
                   "NC": ["New Caledonia","687"],
                   "NZ": ["New Zealand","64"],
                   "NI": ["Nicaragua","505"],
                   "NE": ["Niger","227"],
                   "NG": ["Nigeria","234"],
                   "NU": ["Niue","683"],
                   "NF": ["Norfolk Island","672"],
                   "MP": ["Northern Mariana Islands","1"],
                   "NO": ["Norway","47"],
                   "OM": ["Oman","968"],
                   "PK": ["Pakistan","92"],
                   "PW": ["Palau","680"],
                   "PS": ["Palestinian Territory, Occupied","970"],
                   "PA": ["Panama","507"],
                   "PG": ["Papua New Guinea","675"],
                   "PY": ["Paraguay","595"],
                   "PE": ["Peru","51"],
                   "PH": ["Philippines","63"],
                   "PN": ["Pitcairn","872"],
                   "PL": ["Poland","48"],
                   "PT": ["Portugal","351"],
                   "PR": ["Puerto Rico","1"],
                   "QA": ["Qatar","974"],
                   "RE": ["Réunion","262"],
                   "RO": ["Romania","40"],
                   "RU": ["Russian Federation","7"],
                   "RW": ["Rwanda","250"],
                   "SH": ["Saint Helena","290"],
                   "KN": ["Saint Kitts and Nevis","1"],
                   "LC": ["Saint Lucia","1"],
                   "PM": ["Saint Pierre and Miquelon","508"],
                   "VC": ["Saint Vincent and Grenadines","1"],
                   "BL": ["Saint-Barthélemy","590"],
                   "MF": ["Saint-Martin (French part)","590"],
                   "WS": ["Samoa","685"],
                   "SM": ["San Marino","378"],
                   "ST": ["Sao Tome and Principe","239"],
                   "SA": ["Saudi Arabia","966"],
                   "SN": ["Senegal","221"],
                   "RS": ["Serbia","381"],
                   "SC": ["Seychelles","248"],
                   "SL": ["Sierra Leone","232"],
                   "SG": ["Singapore","65"],
                   "SX": ["Sint Maarten","1"],
                   "SK": ["Slovakia","421"],
                   "SI": ["Slovenia","386"],
                   "SB": ["Solomon Islands","677"],
                   "SO": ["Somalia","252"],
                   "ZA": ["South Africa","27"],
                   "GS": ["South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands","500"],
                   "SS​": ["South Sudan","211"],
                   "ES": ["Spain","34"],
                   "LK": ["Sri Lanka","94"],
                   "SD": ["Sudan","249"],
                   "SR": ["Suriname","597"],
                   "SJ": ["Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands","47"],
                   "SZ": ["Swaziland","268"],
                   "SE": ["Sweden","46"],
                   "CH": ["Switzerland","41"],
                   "SY": ["Syrian Arab Republic (Syria)","963"],
                   "TW": ["Taiwan, Republic of China","886"],
                   "TJ": ["Tajikistan","992"],
                   "TZ": ["Tanzania, United Republic of","255"],
                   "TH": ["Thailand","66"],
                   "TL": ["Timor-Leste","670"],
                   "TG": ["Togo","228"],
                   "TK": ["Tokelau","690"],
                   "TO": ["Tonga","676"],
                   "TT": ["Trinidad and Tobago","1"],
                   "TN": ["Tunisia","216"],
                   "TR": ["Turkey","90"],
                   "TM": ["Turkmenistan","993"],
                   "TC": ["Turks and Caicos Islands","1"],
                   "TV": ["Tuvalu","688"],
                   "UG": ["Uganda","256"],
                   "UA": ["Ukraine","380"],
                   "AE": ["United Arab Emirates","971"],
                   "GB": ["United Kingdom","44"],
                   "US": ["United States of America","1"],
                   "UY": ["Uruguay","598"],
                   "UZ": ["Uzbekistan","998"],
                   "VU": ["Vanuatu","678"],
                   "VE": ["Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)","58"],
                   "VN": ["Viet Nam","84"],
                   "VI": ["Virgin Islands, US","1"],
                   "WF": ["Wallis and Futuna Islands","681"],
                   "EH": ["Western Sahara","212"],
                   "YE": ["Yemen","967"],
                   "ZM": ["Zambia","260"],
                   "ZW": ["Zimbabwe","263"]]

    let countryDialingCode = prefix[countryRegionCode]
    return countryDialingCode!
}
```

Then call above function to use the dialing code & the respective country name to display in the UI.

```
let currentLocale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
let countryCode = currentLocale.objectForKey(NSLocaleCountryCode) as! String
print("Country code according to Locale \(countryCode)")
let countryArray = getCountryCallingCode(countryCode)

print("Country Array according to the Locale \(countryArray)")
print("Country Name \(countryArray[0])")
print("Dialing code \(countryArray[1])")
```

Answer (score 3):

All in one solution : country name with code and flag. and by this code you can also create sections by name. Please support if this really help you

```
self.aryCountryName= [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Afghanistan",@"Albania",@"Algeria",@"Andorra",@"Angola",@"Antigua and Barbuda",@"Argentina",@"Armenia",@"Australia",@"Austria",@"Azerbaijan",@"Bahamas",@"Bahrain",@"Bangladesh",@"Barbados",@"Belarus",@"Belgium",@"Belize",@"Benin",@"Bhutan",@"Bolivia",@"Bosnia and Herzegovina",@"Botswana",@"Brazil",@"Brunei Darussalam",@"Bulgaria",@"Burkina Faso",@"Burundi",@"Cabo Verde",@"Cambodia",@"Cameroon",@"Canada",@"Central African Republic",@"Chad",@"Chile",@"China",@"Colombia",@"Comoros",@"Congo",@"Costa Rica",@"Côte d'Ivoire",@"Croatia",@"Cuba",@"Cyprus",@"Czech Republic",@"Democratic People's Republic of Korea (North Korea)",@"Democratic Republic of the Cong",@"Denmark",@"Djibouti",@"Dominica",@"Dominican Republic",@"Ecuador",@"Egypt",@"El Salvador",@"Equatorial Guinea",@"Eritrea",@"Estonia",@"Ethiopia",@"Fiji",@"Finland",@"France",@"Gabon",@"Gambia",@"Georgia",@"Germany",@"Ghana",@"Greece",@"Grenada",@"Guatemala",@"Guinea",@"Guinea-Bissau",@"Guyana",@"Haiti",@"Honduras",@"Hungary",@"Iceland",@"India",@"Indonesia",@"Iran",@"Iraq",@"Ireland",@"Israel",@"Italy",@"Jamaica",@"Japan",@"Jordan",@"Kazakhstan",@"Kenya",@"Kiribati",@"Kuwait",@"Kyrgyzstan",@"Lao People's Democratic Republic (Laos)",@"Latvia",@"Lebanona",@"Lesotho",@"Liberia",@"Libya",@"Liechtenstein",@"Lithuania",@"Luxembourg",@"Macedonia",@"Madagascar",@"Malawi",@"Malaysia",@"Maldives",@"Mali",@"Malta",@"Marshall Islands",@"Mauritania",@"Mauritius",@"Mexico",@"Micronesia (Federated States of)",@"Monaco",@"Mongolia",@"Montenegro",@"Morocco",@"Mozambique",@"Myanmar",@"Namibia",@"Nauru",@"Nepal",@"Netherlands",@"New Zealand",@"Nicaragua",@"Niger",@"Nigeria",@"Norway",@"Oman",@"pakistan",@"palau",@"panama",@"papua New Guinew",@"Paraguay",@"Peru",@"philippines",@"Poland",@"Portugal",@"Qatar",@"Republic of Korea (South Korea)",@"Republic of Moldova",@"Romania",@"Russian Federation",@"Rwanda",@"Saint Kitts and Nevis",@"Saint Lucia",@"Saint Vincent and the Grenadines",@"Samoa",@"San Marino",@"Sao Tome and Principe",@"Saudi Arabia",@"Senegal",@"Serbia",@"Seychelles",@"Sierra Leone",@"Singapore",@"Slovakia",@"Slovenia",@"Solomon Islands",@"Somalia",@"South Africa",@"South Sudan",@"Spain",@"Sri lanka",@"Sudan",@"Suriname",@"Swaziland",@"Sweden",@"Swazerland",@"Syrian Arab Republic",@"Tajikistan",@"Thailand",@"Timor-Leste",@"Togo",@"Tonga",@"Trinidad and Tobago",@"Tunisia",@"Turkey" ,@" Turkmenistan",@"Tuvalu",@"Uganda",@"Ukraine",@"United Arab Emirates",@"United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland",@"United Republic of Tanzania",@"United States of America",@"Uruguay",@"Uzbekistan",@"Vanuatu",@"Venezuela",@"Vietnam",@"Yemen",@"Zambia",@"Zimbabwe",nil] ;

// Country Code Array
self.aryCountryCode= [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"93",@"355",@"213",@"376",@"244",@"1268",@"54",@"374",@"61",@"43",@"994",@"1242",@"973",@"880",@"1246",@"375",@"32",@"501",@"229",@"975",@"591",@"387",@"267",@"55",@"673",@"359",@"226",@"257",@"238",@"855",@"237",@"1",@"236",@"235",@"56",@"86",@"57",@"269",@"242",@"506",@"225",@"385",@"53",@"357",@"420",@"850",@"243",@"45",@"253",@"1767",@"1809",@"593",@"20",@"503",@"240",@"291",@"372",@"251",@"679",@"358",@"33",@"241",@"220",@"995",@"49",@"233",@"30",@"1473",@"502",@"224",@"245",@"592",@"509",@"504",@"36",@"354",@"91",@"62",@"98",@"964",@"353",@"972",@"39",@"1876",@"81",@"962",@"76",@"254",@"686",@"965",@"996",@"856",@"371",@"961",@"266",@"231",@"218",@"423",@"370",@"352",@"389",@"261",@"265",@"60",@"960",@"223",@"356",@"692",@"222",@"230",@"52",@"691",@"377",@"976",@"382",@"212",@"258",@"95",@"264",@"674",@"977",@"31",@"64",@"505",@"227",@"234",@"47",@"968",@"92",@"680",@"507",@"675",@"595",@"51",@"63",@"48",@"351",@"974",@"82",@"373",@"40",@"7",@"250",@"1869",@"1758",@"1784",@"685",@"378",@"239",@"966",@"221",@"381",@"248",@"232",@"65",@"421",@"386",@"677",@"252",@"27",@"211",@"34",@"94",@"249",@"597",@"268",@"46",@"41",@"963",@"992",@"66",@"670",@"228",@"676",@"1868",@"216",@"90",@"993",@"688",@"256",@"380",@"971",@"44",@"255",@"1",@"598",@"998",@"678",@"58",@"84",@"967",@"260",@"263",nil];

// Country Flag Array
self.aryCountryFlag =[[ NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"af_32.png",@"al_32.png",@"dz_32.png",@"ad_32.png",@"ao_32.png",@"ag_32.png",@"ar_32.png",@"am_32.png",@"au_32.png",@"at_32.png",@"az_32.png",@"bs_32.png",@"bh_32.png",@"bd_32.png",@"bb_32.png",@"by_32.png",@"be_32.png",@"bz_32.png",@"bj_32.png",@"bt_32.png",@"bo_32.png",@"ba_32.png",@"bw_32.png",@"br_32.png",@"bn_32.png",@"bg_32.png",@"bf_32.png",@"bi_32.png",@"cv_32.png",@"kh_32.png",@"cm_32.png",@"ca_32.png",@"cf_32.png",@"td_32.png",@"cl_32.png",@"cn_32.png",@"co_32.png",@"km_32.png",@"cg_32.png",@"cr_32.png",@"ci_32.png",@"hr_32.png",@"cu_32.png",@"cy_32.png",@"cz_32.png",@"kp_32.png",@"cd_32.png",@"dk_32.png",@"dj_32.png",@"dm_32.png",@"do_32.png",@"ec_32.png",@"eg_32.png",@"sv_32.png",@"gq_32.png",@"er_32.png",@"ee_32.png",@"et_32.png",@"fj_32.png",@"fi_32.png",@"fr_32.png",@"ga_32.png",@"gm_32.png",@"ge_32.png",@"de_32.png",@"gh_32.png",@"gr_32.png",@"gd_32.png",@"gt_32.png",@"gn_32.png",@"gw_32.png",@"gy_32.png",@"ht_32.png",@"hn_32.png",@"hu_32.png",@"is_32.png",@"in_32.png",@"id_32.png",@"ir_32.png",@"iq_32.png",@"ie_32.png",@"il_32.png",@"it_32.png",@"jm_32.png",@"jp_32.png",@"jo_32.png",@"kz_32.png",@"ke_32.png",@"ki_32.png",@"kw_32.png",@"kg_32.png",@"la_32.png",@"lv_32.png",@"lb_32.png",@"ls_32.png",@"lr_32.png",@"ly_32.png",@"li_32.png",@"lt_32.png",@"lu_32.png",@"mk_32.png",@"mg_32.png",@"mw_32.png",@"my_32.png",@"mv_32.png",@"ml_32.png",@"mt_32.png",@"mh_32.png",                                  @"mr_32.png",@"mu_32.png",@"mx_32.png",@"fm_32.png",@"mc_32.png",@"mn_32.png",@"me_32.png",@"ma_32.png",@"mz_32.png",@"mm_32.png",@"na_32.png",@"nr_32.png",@"np_32.png",@"nl_32.png",@"nz_32.png",@"ni_32.png",@"ne_32.png",@"ng_32.png",@"no_32.png",@"om_32.png",@"pk_32.png",@"pw_32.png",@"pa_32.png",@"pg_32.png",@"py_32.png",@"pe_32.png",@"ph_32.png",@"pl_32.png",@"pt_32.png",@"qa_32.png",@"kr_32.png",@"md_32.png",@"ro_32.png",@"ru_32.png",@"rw_32.png",@"kn_32.png",@"lc_32.png",@"vc_32.png",@"ws_32.png",@"sm_32.png",@"st_32.png",@"sa_32.png",@"sn_32.png",@"rs_32.png",@"sc_32.png",@"sl_32.png",@"sg_32.png",@"sk_32.png",@"si_32.png",@"sb_32.png",@"so_32.png",@"za_32.png",@"ss_32.png",@"es_32.png",@"lk_32.png",@"sd_32.png",@"sr_32.png",@"sz_32.png",@"se_32.png",@"ch_32.png",@"sy_32.png",@"tj_32.png",@"th_32.png",@"tl_32.png",@"tg_32.png",@"to_32.png",@"tt_32.png",@"tn_32.png",@"tr_32.png",@"tm_32.png",@"tv_32.png",@"ug_32.png",@"ua_32.png",@"ae_32.png",@"gb_32.png",@"tz_32.png",@"us_32.png",@"uy_32.png",@"uz_32.png",@"vu_32.png",@"ve_32.png",@"vn_32.png",@"ye_32.png",@"zm_32.png",@"zw_32.png",nil];

// Counrty Name Dic
self.dicCountryName= @{@"A" : @[@"Afghanistan",@"Albania",@"Algeria",@"Andorra",@"Angola",@"Antigua and Barbuda",@"Argentina",@"Armenia",@"Australia",@"Austria",@"Azerbaijan"],
                       @"B" : @[@"Bahamas",@"Bahrain",@"Bangladesh",@"Barbados",@"Belarus",@"Belgium",@"Belize",@"Benin",@"Bhutan",@"Bolivia",@"Bosnia and Herzegovina",@"Botswana",@"Brazil",@"Brunei Darussalam",@"Bulgaria",@"Burkina Faso",@"Burundi"],
                       @"C" : @[@"Cabo Verde",@"Cambodia",@"Cameroon",@"Canada",@"Central African Republic",@"Chad",@"Chile",@"China",@"Colombia",@"Comoros",@"Congo",@"Costa Rica",@"Côte d'Ivoire",@"Croatia",@"Cuba",@"Cyprus",@"Czech Republic"],
                       @"D" : @[@"Democratic People's Republic of Korea (North Korea)",@"Democratic Republic of the Cong",@"Denmark",@"Djibouti",@"Dominica",@"Dominican Republic"],
                       @"E" : @[@"Ecuador",@"Egypt",@"El Salvador",@"Equatorial Guinea",@"Eritrea",@"Estonia",@"Ethiopia"],
                       @"F" : @[@"Fiji",@"Finland",@"France"],
                       @"G" : @[@"Gabon",@"Gambia",@"Georgia",@"Germany",@"Ghana",@"Greece",@"Grenada",@"Guatemala",@"Guinea",@"Guinea-Bissau",@"Guyana"],
                       @"H" : @[@"Haiti",@"Honduras",@"Hungary"],
                       @"I" : @[@"Iceland",@"India",@"Indonesia",@"Iran",@"Iraq",@"Ireland",@"Israel",@"Italy"],
                       @"J" : @[@"Jamaica",@"Japan",@"Jordan"],
                       @"K" : @[@"Kazakhstan",@"Kenya",@"Kiribati",@"Kuwait",@"Kyrgyzstan"],
                       @"L" : @[@"Lao People's Democratic Republic (Laos)",@"Latvia",@"Lebanona",@"Lesotho",@"Liberia",@"Libya",@"Liechtenstein",@"Lithuania",@"Luxembourg"],
                       @"M" : @[@"Macedonia",@"Madagascar",@"Malawi",@"Malaysia",@"Maldives",@"Mali",@"Malta",@"Marshall Islands",@"Mauritania",@"Mauritius",@"Mexico",@"Micronesia (Federated States of)",@"Monaco",@"Mongolia",@"Montenegro",@"Morocco",@"Mozambique",@"Myanmar"],
                       @"N" : @[@"Namibia",@"Nauru",@"Nepal",@"Netherlands",@"New Zealand",@"Nicaragua",@"Niger",@"Nigeria",@"Norway"],
                       @"O" : @[@"Oman"],
                       @"P" : @[@"pakistan",@"palau",@"panama",@"papua New Guinew",@"Paraguay",@"Peru",@"philippines",@"Poland",@"Portugal"],
                       @"Q" : @[@"Qatar"],
                       @"R" : @[@"Republic of Korea (South Korea)",@"Republic of Moldova",@"Romania",@"Russian Federation",@"Rwanda"],
                       @"S" : @[@"Saint Kitts and Nevis",@"Saint Lucia",@"Saint Vincent and the Grenadines",@"Samoa",@"San Marino",@"Sao Tome and Principe",@"Saudi Arabia",@"Senegal",@"Serbia",@"Seychelles",@"Sierra Leone",@"Singapore",@"Slovakia",@"Slovenia",@"Solomon Islands",@"Somalia",@"South Africa",@"South Sudan",@"Spain",@"Sri lanka",@"Sudan",@"Suriname",@"Swaziland",@"Sweden",@"Swazerland",@"Syrian Arab Republic"],
                       @"T" : @[@"Tajikistan",@"Thailand",@"Timor-Leste",@"Togo",@"Tonga",@"Trinidad and Tobago",@"Tunisia",@"Turkey" ,@" Turkmenistan",@"Tuvalu"],
                       @"U" : @[@"Uganda",@"Ukraine",@"United Arab Emirates",@"United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland",@"United Republic of Tanzania",@"United States of America",@"Uruguay",@"Uzbekistan"],
                       @"V" : @[@"Vanuatu",@"Venezuela",@"Vietnam"],
                       @"Y" : @[@"Yemen"],
                       @"Z" : @[@"Zambia",@"Zimbabwe"]};

 // Country Code Dic
self.dicCountryCode = @{@"A" : @[@"93",@"355",@"213",@"376",@"244",@"1268",@"54",@"374",@"61",@"43",@"994"],
                        @"B" : @[@"1242",@"973",@"880",@"1246",@"375",@"32",@"501",@"229",@"975",@"591",@"387",@"267",@"55",@"673",@"359",@"226",@"257"],
                        @"C" : @[@"238",@"855",@"237",@"1",@"236",@"235",@"56",@"86",@"57",@"269",@"242",@"506",@"225",@"385",@"53",@"357",@"420"],
                        @"D" : @[@"850",@"243",@"45",@"253",@"1767",@"1809"],
                        @"E" : @[@"593",@"20",@"503",@"240",@"291",@"372",@"251"],
                        @"F" : @[@"679",@"358",@"33"],
                        @"G" : @[@"241",@"220",@"995",@"49",@"233",@"30",@"1473",@"502",@"224",@"245",@"592"],
                        @"H" : @[@"509",@"504",@"36"],
                        @"I" : @[@"354",@"91",@"62",@"98",@"964",@"353",@"972",@"39"],
                        @"J" : @[@"1876",@"81",@"962"],
                        @"K" : @[@"76",@"254",@"686",@"965",@"996"],
                        @"L" : @[@"856",@"371",@"961",@"266",@"231",@"218",@"423",@"370",@"352"],
                        @"M" :@[@"389",@"261",@"265",@"60",@"960",@"223",@"356",@"692",@"222",@"230",@"52",@"691",@"377",@"976",@"382",@"212",@"258",@"95"],
                        @"N" : @[@"264",@"674",@"977",@"31",@"64",@"505",@"227",@"234",@"47"],
                        @"O" : @[@"968"],
                        @"P" : @[@"92",@"680",@"507",@"675",@"595",@"51",@"63",@"48",@"351"],
                        @"Q" : @[@"974"],
                        @"R" : @[@"82",@"373",@"40",@"7",@"250"],
                        @"S" : @[@"1869",@"1758",@"1784",@"685",@"378",@"239",@"966",@"221",@"381",@"248",@"232",@"65",@"421",@"386",@"677",@"252",@"27",@"211",@"34",@"94",@"249",@"597",@"268",@"46",@"41",@"963"],
                        @"T" : @[@"992",@"66",@"670",@"228",@"676",@"1868",@"216",@"90",@"993",@"688"],
                        @"U" : @[@"256",@"380",@"971",@"44",@"255",@"1",@"598",@"998"],
                        @"V" : @[@"678",@"58",@"84"],
                        @"Y" : @[@"967"],
                        @"Z" : @[@"260",@"263"]};


// Country Flag Dic is below
self.dicCountryFlag = @{@"A" : @[@"af_32.png",@"al_32.png",@"dz_32.png",@"ad_32.png",@"ao_32.png",@"ag_32.png",@"ar_32.png",@"am_32.png",@"au_32.png",@"at_32.png",@"az_32.png"],
                        @"B" : @[@"bs_32.png",@"bh_32.png",@"bd_32.png",@"bb_32.png",@"by_32.png",@"be_32.png",@"bz_32.png",@"bj_32.png",@"bt_32.png",@"bo_32.png",@"ba_32.png",@"bw_32.png",@"br_32.png",@"bn_32.png",@"bg_32.png",@"bf_32.png",@"bi_32.png"],
                        @"C" : @[@"cv_32.png",@"kh_32.png",@"cm_32.png",@"ca_32.png",@"cf_32.png",@"td_32.png",@"cl_32.png",@"cn_32.png",@"co_32.png",@"km_32.png",@"cg_32.png",@"cr_32.png",@"ci_32.png",@"hr_32.png",@"cu_32.png",@"cy_32.png",@"cz_32.png"],
                        @"D" : @[@"kp_32.png",@"cd_32.png",@"dk_32.png",@"dj_32.png",@"dm_32.png",@"do_32.png"],
                        @"E" : @[@"ec_32.png",@"eg_32.png",@"sv_32.png",@"gq_32.png",@"er_32.png",@"ee_32.png",@"et_32.png"],
                        @"F" : @[@"fj_32.png",@"fi_32.png",@"fr_32.png"],
                        @"G" : @[@"ga_32.png",@"gm_32.png",@"ge_32.png",@"de_32.png",@"gh_32.png",@"gr_32.png",@"gd_32.png",@"gt_32.png",@"gn_32.png",@"gw_32.png",@"gy_32.png"],
                        @"H" : @[@"ht_32.png",@"hn_32.png",@"hu_32.png"],
                        @"I" : @[@"is_32.png",@"in_32.png",@"id_32.png",@"ir_32.png",@"iq_32.png",@"ie_32.png",@"il_32.png",@"it_32.png"],
                        @"J" : @[@"jm_32.png",@"jp_32.png",@"jo_32.png"],
                        @"K" : @[@"kz_32.png",@"ke_32.png",@"ki_32.png",@"kw_32.png",@"kg_32.png"],
                        @"L" : @[@"la_32.png",@"lv_32.png",@"lb_32.png",@"ls_32.png",@"lr_32.png",@"ly_32.png",@"li_32.png",@"lt_32.png",@"lu_32.png"],
                        @"M" :@[@"mk_32.png",@"mg_32.png",@"mw_32.png",@"my_32.png",@"mv_32.png",@"ml_32.png",@"mt_32.png",@"mh_32.png",                                  @"mr_32.png",@"mu_32.png",@"mx_32.png",@"fm_32.png",@"mc_32.png",@"mn_32.png",@"me_32.png",@"ma_32.png",@"mz_32.png",@"mm_32.png"],
                        @"N" : @[@"na_32.png",@"nr_32.png",@"np_32.png",@"nl_32.png",@"nz_32.png",@"ni_32.png",@"ne_32.png",@"ng_32.png",@"no_32.png"],
                        @"O" : @[@"om_32.png"],
                        @"P" : @[@"pk_32.png",@"pw_32.png",@"pa_32.png",@"pg_32.png",@"py_32.png",@"pe_32.png",@"ph_32.png",@"pl_32.png",@"pt_32.png"],
                        @"Q" : @[@"qa_32.png"],
                        @"R" : @[@"kr_32.png",@"md_32.png",@"ro_32.png",@"ru_32.png",@"rw_32.png"],
                        @"S" : @[@"kn_32.png",@"lc_32.png",@"vc_32.png",@"ws_32.png",@"sm_32.png",@"st_32.png",@"sa_32.png",@"sn_32.png",@"rs_32.png",@"sc_32.png",@"sl_32.png",@"sg_32.png",@"sk_32.png",@"si_32.png",@"sb_32.png",@"so_32.png",@"za_32.png",@"ss_32.png",@"es_32.png",@"lk_32.png",@"sd_32.png",@"sr_32.png",@"sz_32.png",@"se_32.png",@"ch_32.png",@"sy_32.png"],
                        @"T" : @[@"tj_32.png",@"th_32.png",@"tl_32.png",@"tg_32.png",@"to_32.png",@"tt_32.png",@"tn_32.png",@"tr_32.png",@"tm_32.png",@"tv_32.png"],
                        @"U" : @[@"ug_32.png",@"ua_32.png",@"ae_32.png",@"gb_32.png",@"tz_32.png",@"us_32.png",@"uy_32.png",@"uz_32.png"],
                        @"V" : @[@"vu_32.png",@"ve_32.png",@"vn_32.png"],
                        @"Y" : @[@"ye_32.png"],
                        @"Z" : @[@"zm_32.png",@"zw_32.png"]};

self.countryIndexTitles = @[@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X", @"Y", @"Z"];

}
```

Comment: Do you have a download link somewhere for the flag images? Would be a huge help. Thanks!

Comment: @BJHStudios no bro.i do not have.sorry

Answer (score 3):

With full country names:

```
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         @[@"Afghanistan",@"93"],@"AF",
                         @[@"Aland Islands",@"358"],@"AX",
                         @[@"Albania",@"355"],@"AL",
                         @[@"Algeria",@"213"],@"DZ",
                         @[@"American Samoa",@"1"],@"AS",
                         @[@"Andorra",@"376"],@"AD",
                         @[@"Angola",@"244"],@"AO",
                         @[@"Anguilla",@"1"],@"AI",
                         @[@"Antarctica",@"672"],@"AQ",
                         @[@"Antigua and Barbuda",@"1"],@"AG",
                         @[@"Argentina",@"54"],@"AR",
                         @[@"Armenia",@"374"],@"AM",
                         @[@"Aruba",@"297"],@"AW",
                         @[@"Australia",@"61"],@"AU",
                         @[@"Austria",@"43"],@"AT",
                         @[@"Azerbaijan",@"994"],@"AZ",
                         @[@"Bahamas",@"1"],@"BS",
                         @[@"Bahrain",@"973"],@"BH",
                         @[@"Bangladesh",@"880"],@"BD",
                         @[@"Barbados",@"1"],@"BB",
                         @[@"Belarus",@"375"],@"BY",
                         @[@"Belgium",@"32"],@"BE",
                         @[@"Belize",@"501"],@"BZ",
                         @[@"Benin",@"229"],@"BJ",
                         @[@"Bermuda",@"1"],@"BM",
                         @[@"Bhutan",@"975"],@"BT",
                         @[@"Bolivia",@"591"],@"BO",
                         @[@"Bosnia and Herzegovina",@"387"],@"BA",
                         @[@"Botswana",@"267"],@"BW",
                         @[@"Bouvet Island",@"47"],@"BV",
                         @[@"BQ",@"599"],@"BQ",
                         @[@"Brazil",@"55"],@"BR",
                         @[@"British Indian Ocean Territory",@"246"],@"IO",
                         @[@"British Virgin Islands",@"1"],@"VG",
                         @[@"Brunei Darussalam",@"673"],@"BN",
                         @[@"Bulgaria",@"359"],@"BG",
                         @[@"Burkina Faso",@"226"],@"BF",
                         @[@"Burundi",@"257"],@"BI",
                         @[@"Cambodia",@"855"],@"KH",
                         @[@"Cameroon",@"237"],@"CM",
                         @[@"Canada",@"1"],@"CA",
                         @[@"Cape Verde",@"238"],@"CV",
                         @[@"Cayman Islands",@"345"],@"KY",
                         @[@"Central African Republic",@"236"],@"CF",
                         @[@"Chad",@"235"],@"TD",
                         @[@"Chile",@"56"],@"CL",
                         @[@"China",@"86"],@"CN",
                         @[@"Christmas Island",@"61"],@"CX",
                         @[@"Cocos (Keeling) Islands",@"61"],@"CC",
                         @[@"Colombia",@"57"],@"CO",
                         @[@"Comoros",@"269"],@"KM",
                         @[@"Congo (Brazzaville)",@"242"],@"CG",
                         @[@"Congo, Democratic Republic of the",@"243"],@"CD",
                         @[@"Cook Islands",@"682"],@"CK",
                         @[@"Costa Rica",@"506"],@"CR",
                         @[@"Côte d'Ivoire",@"225"],@"CI",
                         @[@"Croatia",@"385"],@"HR",
                         @[@"Cuba",@"53"],@"CU",
                         @[@"Curacao",@"599"],@"CW",
                         @[@"Cyprus",@"537"],@"CY",
                         @[@"Czech Republic",@"420"],@"CZ",
                         @[@"Denmark",@"45"],@"DK",
                         @[@"Djibouti",@"253"],@"DJ",
                         @[@"Dominica",@"1"],@"DM",
                         @[@"Dominican Republic",@"1"],@"DO",
                         @[@"Ecuador",@"593"],@"EC",
                         @[@"Egypt",@"20"],@"EG",
                         @[@"El Salvador",@"503"],@"SV",
                         @[@"Equatorial Guinea",@"240"],@"GQ",
                         @[@"Eritrea",@"291"],@"ER",
                         @[@"Estonia",@"372"],@"EE",
                         @[@"Ethiopia",@"251"],@"ET",
                         @[@"Falkland Islands (Malvinas)",@"500"],@"FK",
                         @[@"Faroe Islands",@"298"],@"FO",
                         @[@"Fiji",@"679"],@"FJ",
                         @[@"Finland",@"358"],@"FI",
                         @[@"France",@"33"],@"FR",
                         @[@"French Guiana",@"594"],@"GF",
                         @[@"French Polynesia",@"689"],@"PF",
                         @[@"French Southern Territories",@"689"],@"TF",
                         @[@"Gabon",@"241"],@"GA",
                         @[@"Gambia",@"220"],@"GM",
                         @[@"Georgia",@"995"],@"GE",
                         @[@"Germany",@"49"],@"DE",
                         @[@"Ghana",@"233"],@"GH",
                         @[@"Gibraltar",@"350"],@"GI",
                         @[@"Greece",@"30"],@"GR",
                         @[@"Greenland",@"299"],@"GL",
                         @[@"Grenada",@"1"],@"GD",
                         @[@"Guadeloupe",@"590"],@"GP",
                         @[@"Guam",@"1"],@"GU",
                         @[@"Guatemala",@"502"],@"GT",
                         @[@"Guernsey",@"44"],@"GG",
                         @[@"Guinea",@"224"],@"GN",
                         @[@"Guinea-Bissau",@"245"],@"GW",
                         @[@"Guyana",@"595"],@"GY",
                         @[@"Haiti",@"509"],@"HT",
                         @[@"Holy See (Vatican City State)",@"379"],@"VA",
                         @[@"Honduras",@"504"],@"HN",
                         @[@"Hong Kong, Special Administrative Region of China",@"852"],@"HK",
                         @[@"Hungary",@"36"],@"HU",
                         @[@"Iceland",@"354"],@"IS",
                         @[@"India",@"91"],@"IN",
                         @[@"Indonesia",@"62"],@"ID",
                         @[@"Iran, Islamic Republic of",@"98"],@"IR",
                         @[@"Iraq",@"964"],@"IQ",
                         @[@"Ireland",@"353"],@"IE",
                         @[@"Isle of Man",@"44"],@"IM",
                         @[@"Israel",@"972"],@"IL",
                         @[@"Italy",@"39"],@"IT",
                         @[@"Jamaica",@"1"],@"JM",
                         @[@"Japan",@"81"],@"JP",
                         @[@"Jersey",@"44"],@"JE",
                         @[@"Jordan",@"962"],@"JO",
                         @[@"Kazakhstan",@"77"],@"KZ",
                         @[@"Kenya",@"254"],@"KE",
                         @[@"Kiribati",@"686"],@"KI",
                         @[@"Korea, Democratic People's Republic of",@"850"],@"KP",
                         @[@"Korea, Republic of",@"82"],@"KR",
                         @[@"Kuwait",@"965"],@"KW",
                         @[@"Kyrgyzstan",@"996"],@"KG",
                         @[@"Lao PDR",@"856"],@"LA",
                         @[@"Latvia",@"371"],@"LV",
                         @[@"Lebanon",@"961"],@"LB",
                         @[@"Lesotho",@"266"],@"LS",
                         @[@"Liberia",@"231"],@"LR",
                         @[@"Libya",@"218"],@"LY",
                         @[@"Liechtenstein",@"423"],@"LI",
                         @[@"Lithuania",@"370"],@"LT",
                         @[@"Luxembourg",@"352"],@"LU",
                         @[@"Macao, Special Administrative Region of China",@"853"],@"MO",
                         @[@"Macedonia, Republic of",@"389"],@"MK",
                         @[@"Madagascar",@"261"],@"MG",
                         @[@"Malawi",@"265"],@"MW",
                         @[@"Malaysia",@"60"],@"MY",
                         @[@"Maldives",@"960"],@"MV",
                         @[@"Mali",@"223"],@"ML",
                         @[@"Malta",@"356"],@"MT",
                         @[@"Marshall Islands",@"692"],@"MH",
                         @[@"Martinique",@"596"],@"MQ",
                         @[@"Mauritania",@"222"],@"MR",
                         @[@"Mauritius",@"230"],@"MU",
                         @[@"Mayotte",@"262"],@"YT",
                         @[@"Mexico",@"52"],@"MX",
                         @[@"Micronesia, Federated States of",@"691"],@"FM",
                         @[@"Moldova",@"373"],@"MD",
                         @[@"Monaco",@"377"],@"MC",
                         @[@"Mongolia",@"976"],@"MN",
                         @[@"Montenegro",@"382"],@"ME",
                         @[@"Montserrat",@"1"],@"MS",
                         @[@"Morocco",@"212"],@"MA",
                         @[@"Mozambique",@"258"],@"MZ",
                         @[@"Myanmar",@"95"],@"MM",
                         @[@"Namibia",@"264"],@"NA",
                         @[@"Nauru",@"674"],@"NR",
                         @[@"Nepal",@"977"],@"NP",
                         @[@"Netherlands",@"31"],@"NL",
                         @[@"Netherlands Antilles",@"599"],@"AN",
                         @[@"New Caledonia",@"687"],@"NC",
                         @[@"New Zealand",@"64"],@"NZ",
                         @[@"Nicaragua",@"505"],@"NI",
                         @[@"Niger",@"227"],@"NE",
                         @[@"Nigeria",@"234"],@"NG",
                         @[@"Niue",@"683"],@"NU",
                         @[@"Norfolk Island",@"672"],@"NF",
                         @[@"Northern Mariana Islands",@"1"],@"MP",
                         @[@"Norway",@"47"],@"NO",
                         @[@"Oman",@"968"],@"OM",
                         @[@"Pakistan",@"92"],@"PK",
                         @[@"Palau",@"680"],@"PW",
                         @[@"Palestinian Territory, Occupied",@"970"],@"PS",
                         @[@"Panama",@"507"],@"PA",
                         @[@"Papua New Guinea",@"675"],@"PG",
                         @[@"Paraguay",@"595"],@"PY",
                         @[@"Peru",@"51"],@"PE",
                         @[@"Philippines",@"63"],@"PH",
                         @[@"Pitcairn",@"872"],@"PN",
                         @[@"Poland",@"48"],@"PL",
                         @[@"Portugal",@"351"],@"PT",
                         @[@"Puerto Rico",@"1"],@"PR",
                         @[@"Qatar",@"974"],@"QA",
                         @[@"Réunion",@"262"],@"RE",
                         @[@"Romania",@"40"],@"RO",
                         @[@"Russian Federation",@"7"],@"RU",
                         @[@"Rwanda",@"250"],@"RW",
                         @[@"Saint Helena",@"290"],@"SH",
                         @[@"Saint Kitts and Nevis",@"1"],@"KN",
                         @[@"Saint Lucia",@"1"],@"LC",
                         @[@"Saint Pierre and Miquelon",@"508"],@"PM",
                         @[@"Saint Vincent and Grenadines",@"1"],@"VC",
                         @[@"Saint-Barthélemy",@"590"],@"BL",
                         @[@"Saint-Martin (French part)",@"590"],@"MF",
                         @[@"Samoa",@"685"],@"WS",
                         @[@"San Marino",@"378"],@"SM",
                         @[@"Sao Tome and Principe",@"239"],@"ST",
                         @[@"Saudi Arabia",@"966"],@"SA",
                         @[@"Senegal",@"221"],@"SN",
                         @[@"Serbia",@"381"],@"RS",
                         @[@"Seychelles",@"248"],@"SC",
                         @[@"Sierra Leone",@"232"],@"SL",
                         @[@"Singapore",@"65"],@"SG",
                         @[@"Sint Maarten",@"1"],@"SX",
                         @[@"Slovakia",@"421"],@"SK",
                         @[@"Slovenia",@"386"],@"SI",
                         @[@"Solomon Islands",@"677"],@"SB",
                         @[@"Somalia",@"252"],@"SO",
                         @[@"South Africa",@"27"],@"ZA",
                         @[@"South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands",@"500"],@"GS",
                         @[@"South Sudan",@"211"],@"SS​",
                         @[@"Spain",@"34"],@"ES",
                         @[@"Sri Lanka",@"94"],@"LK",
                         @[@"Sudan",@"249"],@"SD",
                         @[@"Suriname",@"597"],@"SR",
                         @[@"Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands",@"47"],@"SJ",
                         @[@"Swaziland",@"268"],@"SZ",
                         @[@"Sweden",@"46"],@"SE",
                         @[@"Switzerland",@"41"],@"CH",
                         @[@"Syrian Arab Republic (Syria)",@"963"],@"SY",
                         @[@"Taiwan, Republic of China",@"886"],@"TW",
                         @[@"Tajikistan",@"992"],@"TJ",
                         @[@"Tanzania, United Republic of",@"255"],@"TZ",
                         @[@"Thailand",@"66"],@"TH",
                         @[@"Timor-Leste",@"670"],@"TL",
                         @[@"Togo",@"228"],@"TG",
                         @[@"Tokelau",@"690"],@"TK",
                         @[@"Tonga",@"676"],@"TO",
                         @[@"Trinidad and Tobago",@"1"],@"TT",
                         @[@"Tunisia",@"216"],@"TN",
                         @[@"Turkey",@"90"],@"TR",
                         @[@"Turkmenistan",@"993"],@"TM",
                         @[@"Turks and Caicos Islands",@"1"],@"TC",
                         @[@"Tuvalu",@"688"],@"TV",
                         @[@"Uganda",@"256"],@"UG",
                         @[@"Ukraine",@"380"],@"UA",
                         @[@"United Arab Emirates",@"971"],@"AE",
                         @[@"United Kingdom",@"44"],@"GB",
                         @[@"United States of America",@"1"],@"US",
                         @[@"Uruguay",@"598"],@"UY",
                         @[@"Uzbekistan",@"998"],@"UZ",
                         @[@"Vanuatu",@"678"],@"VU",
                         @[@"Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)",@"58"],@"VE",
                         @[@"Viet Nam",@"84"],@"VN",
                         @[@"Virgin Islands, US",@"1"],@"VI",
                         @[@"Wallis and Futuna Islands",@"681"],@"WF",
                         @[@"Western Sahara",@"212"],@"EH",
                         @[@"Yemen",@"967"],@"YE",
                         @[@"Zambia",@"260"],@"ZM",
                         @[@"Zimbabwe",@"263"],@"ZW", nil];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use info from [here](http://country.io/data/).

You can take `code:name` from [here](http://country.io/names.json)
and combine with `code:phoneCode` [here](http://country.io/phone.json)

Information there is always up-to-date and you can download it in app at any time. So you can be sure that you always have latest info about phone codes

Answer (score 1):

Use `NSLocale`:

```
let countries = NSLocale.ISOCountryCodes().flatMap({
    (code) -> [String:String]? in
    let id = NSLocale.localeIdentifierFromComponents([NSLocaleCountryCode: code])
    if let name = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: NSLocale.currentLocale().localeIdentifier).displayNameForKey(NSLocaleIdentifier, value: id) {
        return ["name" : name, "code" : code]
    }

    return nil
})
```

Comment: Question require dialling codes, not country codes.