# Converting property lists into Objective-C literals

Tags: objective-c, plist, objective-c-literals

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I've seen people do crazy things with regex and other tools.

I want to convert [this plist](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-patch/source/browse/trunk/bgfix/UIKit.framework/PhoneFormats/UIPhoneFormats.plist?r=7) to an Objective-C literals:

```
<dict>
    <key>ar</key>
    <array>
        <string>+54## #### ####</string>
        <string>## #### ####</string>
    </array>
    <key>at</key>
    <array>
        <string>+43 1 ########</string>
        <string>+43 ############</string>

</dict>
```

converted to:

```
NSDictionary *dic = @{ 
     @"ar" : @[@"+54## #### ####", @"## #### ####"],
     @"at" : @[@"+43 1 ########",@"+43 ############"]
};
```

Is it possible to automate such conversion? [This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13022975/458960) did something similiar: he parsed a PHP list into an NSDictionary using VIM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Plist don't have a separate 'format' for use in code (this question doesn't quite make sense as-is). You either want to 1. generate Objective-C code which initializes the dictionary with these values, or 2. initialize the dictionary using the file, for which you can write

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"UIPhoneFormats.plist"];
```

**Edit:** so you want to generate Objective-C code that in turn will reproduce the same dictionary. For this, you need to re-print the contents of the dictionary in a formatted way. You can write a program like this:

```
#import <stdio.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NSString *recursiveDump(id object)
{
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@\"%@\"", object];
    } else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@", object];
    } else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
        NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"@["];
        NSInteger size = [object count];
        NSInteger i;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (i > 0) [str appendString:@", "];
            [str appendString:recursiveDump([object objectAtIndex:i])];
        }
        [str appendString:@"]"];
        return str;
    } else if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"@{"];
        NSString *key;
        NSInteger size = [object count];
        NSArray *keys = [object allKeys];
        NSInteger i;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (i > 0) [str appendString:@", "];
            key = [keys objectAtIndex:i];
            [str appendFormat:@"%@: %@", recursiveDump(key), recursiveDump([object objectForKey:key])];
        }
        [str appendString:@"}"];
        return str;
    } else {
        // feel free to implement handling NSData and NSDate here,
        // it's not that straighforward as it is for basic data types.
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"UIPhoneFormats.plist"];
    NSMutableString *code = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"NSDictionary *dict = "];
    [code appendString:recursiveDump(dict)];
    [code appendString:@";"];
    printf("%s\n", [code UTF8String]);

    [pool release];
    return 0;
}
```

This program will generate (hopefully syntax error-free) Objective-C initialization code out of the provided property list which can be copy-pasted to a project and be used.

**Edit:** I just run the program on a stripped version of the plist file OP has provided (the original file was *way too large,* so I cut it a bit) and it generated the following code:

```
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"at": @[@"+43 1 ########", @"+43 ############", @"01 ########", @"00 $"], @"ar": @[@"+54## #### ####", @"## #### ####", @"00 $", @"18 ### $ "]};
```

To verify it was really valid, I pasted this into the middle of an `int main()` to a file called 'test.m', so I got this program:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main()
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"at": @[@"+43 1 ########", @"+43 ############", @"0$
    NSLog(@"%@", dict);

    [pool release];
    return 0;
}
```

To verify, I run `clang -o test test.m -lobjc -framework Foundation` and surprise, surprise:

[It worked.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPued.png)

**Edit 2:** I made this a command line utility, just to facilitate further work - who knows, this may be useful in the future. [Plist2ObjC](https://github.com/H2CO3/Plist2ObjC)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sure, posted that before refreshing.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is [Serializing a Property List](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/SerializePlist/SerializePlist.html)

```
NSData* plistData = [source dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *error;
NSPropertyListFormat format;
NSDictionary* plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistData mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&format errorDescription:&error];
NSLog( @"plist is %@", plist );
if(!plist){
        NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
        [error release];
}
```

If you want to get it as a string, use this,

```
NSString *aString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", plist];
```

or else you can call `NSString *aString = [plist description]` to get the same as a string.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1072308/parse-plist-nsstring-into-nsdictionary)

Comment: Yes but this just keeps the dictionary in the system. I want a code format of the dictionary.

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the whole things as a text/string?

Comment: I just want to convert it to code format so I can have an editable NSDictionary in one of my methods, like this: http://pastebin.com/adNADRzU

Comment: @mohabitar So basically you want to **generate Objective-C code that results in you having an NSDictionary literal with the same contents as the file you gave us a link to,** right?

Comment: @mohabitar wait a bit, I'll update my answer with the necessary info.

Comment: @mohabitar, I have updated my answer. Check if that is what you wanted.

Comment: @ACB One. This will give the old-style (OpenStep) representation of the propertly list, which is not what OP is looking for. Two, this won't generate valid Objective-C code (because of its format and the lack of an initialization statement). Three, `-description` is not to be relied on, it can change in future revisions of Foundation.

Comment: Can you please explain why 'this wont generate valid Objective-C code'? I didnt quite get it. As far as I know, this will generate a string in NSDictionary format which we normally used to display in console.

Comment: @ACB Yes, but as I said, that is the old OpenStep format, which you can't use directly for creating object literals, because it's not Objective-C code, it's just similar.

Comment: It is true that it is the earlier format, but [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", plist]; will generate a valid string. I am not sure what you meant by Objective-C code.

Comment: @ACB OP wants to convert the contents of a given property list to Objective-C code which he can copy-paste and compile.

Comment: Sorry, got confused with the question then. In that case you are right.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18536/discussion-between-h2co3-and-acb)

Answer (score 0):

In the latest macOS, there is a utility called plutil which can convert plists into a variety of formats.  If you run it like this:

% plutil -convert objc -o output.m file.plist

Then it will generate a file called output.m which contains the objective-C initializer the matches the data in file.plist.